# Validate a Radio check if a select box is selected, jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Hi im making an app on Rails,

Ruby on Rails.. This is Why i copied all the HTML, because one of the doubts i have its because of the ids, generated like that, and classes, and name..

If it where a simple HMTL , i will not have this doubts, sorry if it is not a simple HTML, but thats exactly why i do the question,

but my issue is using validate of jquery. I have a code that inserts a row for "achievements" to user, he can add as much as he wants.

The problem is that i need to force them to select , "club" or "national team"

The problem is that i will have multiple ids, cause every item added will have a new id..

how can i make this work..

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wt57R/2/

And this is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


      // validate signup form on keyup and submit
$(".edit_player").validate({ // initialize the plugin
        errorElement: 'div'});

$("#name").rules("add", { required: true,  messages: { required: "<%= t('generales.camporequerido') %>"}});
$("#email").rules("add", { required: true, maxlength: 280, });


    jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    required: "<%= t('generales.camporequerido') %>",
    remote: "Please fix this field.",
    email: "Ingresa un correo electrónico válido.",
    url: "Please enter a valid URL.",
    date: "Please enter a valid date.",
    dateISO: "Please enter a valid date (ISO).",
    number: "Please enter a valid number.",
    digits: "Please enter only digits.",
    creditcard: "Please enter a valid credit card number.",
    equalTo: "Please enter the same value again.",
    accept: "Please enter a value with a valid extension.",
    maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter no more than {0} characters."),
    minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter at least {0} characters."),
    rangelength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1} characters long."),
    range: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1}."),
    max: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}."),
    min: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}.")
});


  });
```

Comment: set one as the default value. when you are generating the radio buttons, add attribute `checked="checked"` to the first `<input type="radio"/>`. if the user wants he can select the other one.

Comment: Can't you just break this down into only the bare minimum amount of code **necessary** to show an example of your problem?  That's what we mean by _'making a "concise" demo'_.  In other words, when the problem is with a handful of `radio` buttons, you don't need to show us NINE `select` elements, three with 4 `option`'s, three with 12 `option`'s, and three with 65 `option` elements!  That's more than 250 lines of unnecessary noise.

Comment: **Quote:** _"The problem is that i need to force them to select , 'club' or 'national team'  The problem is that i will have multiple ids, cause every item added will have a new id"_ ~  Your problem is very unclear.  If you make the `radio` group required, then they will be forced to select one or the other, just like you want.  Every group has a unique `name`... that is not a problem... that's what you want.  From the code you've shown, you'll simply need to add the `required` rule to the `radio` buttons.

Comment: This HTML is generated by a GEM in rails, thats why i copied the HTML printed , also in rails a lot of items have the same id, and its not causing a problem, i aven read about this , its not a malfunction in gem its the way it suppose to work

Comment: If it where a simple HMTL , i will not have this doubts, sorry if it is not a simple HTML, but thats exactly why i do the question,

Comment: Thanks @ th1rdey3 at least you point in one direction.